# Spring MVC doesn't run when deployed on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a webapp that runs fine with maven: mvn tomcat:run

But, when i deploy a jar with: mvn package
and publish it on my tomcat-6.0.20 server, it doesn't run ...

Trace:

```
13/06/2013 18:40:19 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
13/06/2013 18:40:20 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getResourceLoader()Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getResourceLoader()Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.configureScanner(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:100)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:83)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:69)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1114)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:280)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:100)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:298)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:241)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3934)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:850)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1206)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
13/06/2013 18:40:20 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

The dependency: spring-modules-validation was adding a Spring2.0.3.jar in the classpath.

I've had to exclude it from maven dependency

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't have the `spring-beans` jar in your classpath. Can you check that ?

Comment: Not explicit, but it was there as a dependency resolution of maven. I added it explicit, but the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your spring dependency as provided in Maven then provide it via lib folder on Tomcat? Cross check you have matching version of Spring, and all required dependencies are there

If you set it to compile, check your Tomcat lib folder for spring dependencies, having duplicate spring jars of conflicting version might also cause issue

Comment: All my Spring libs are set as compile, and i added nothing to tomcat lib folder =/